# Find missing random amount of numbers in array with duplicates

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, complexity-theory

I should have a complete array of numeric identifiers like this one:

```rb
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But instead, I have a a messed up array in random order, with duplicates and missing numbers like this one:

```rb
b = [4, 9, 7, 7, 3, 3]
```

Is there a more optimal way to find out which numbers are missing apart from substract the array without duplicates?

```rb
a - b.uniq
```

Comment: is `a` always in the form of [1..n] ?

Comment: No. I have basically a list of any numbers and need to make sure that something is missing.

Comment: just `a - b`, `uniq` is redundant here

Comment: Re your reply to @jrook, I suggest you edit to change `a` so that it does not include all integers in a range. Moreover, if `a` is not necessarily ordered, have some elements out of order. If `a` is ordered, say so.

Comment: @Elo but "No. I have basically a list of any numbers and need to make sure that something is missing" changes the task significantly. It means you don't have `a` in advance, right? Or what?

Comment: I don't have `a` but i can get the minimum and maximum value to get the range, and since i expect to get a full array from minimum to maximum i can build it.

Comment: @jrook asked you (first comment) if `a` is a range (or a range converted to an array). You said, "no". In your last comment above you seem to say it is a range. Is it? That may be important. If, so, leave `a` a range (which can be converted to an array if desirable). Please edit your question to clarify rather than doing so in comments, which are not necessarily read by all readers.

Comment: A suggestion: this could be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You may get better overall solutions if you could explain the process that generates `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 2.6 introduced [`Array#difference`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-difference) which seems perfect here:

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [4, 9, 7, 7, 3, 3]

a.difference(b)
# => [5, 6, 8, 10]
```

Seems handy for this, with the added benefit of being very readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
(a - b).empty?
```

works, but--depending on the data--it may not be the fastest way of determining if `a` contains an element not in `b`. For example, the probability were high that every element of `a` was not in `b`, it might be faster, on average, to check if `a[0]` is in `b`, then (if it is not) if `a[1]` is in `b` and so on, stopping if and when the element is in `b`. But again, that depends on the data, in particular the likelihood that `(a - b).empty?` is `true`. If that likelihood is great, [Array#-](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2D), which is written in C, would be relatively fast and probably the best choice.

On the other hand, if its all but certain that `a` will contain many elements that is not in `b` it may be faster to do something like the following:

```
require 'set'

b_set = b.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {4, 9, 7, 3}> 
a.all? { |n| b_set.include?(n) }
```

In any event, you might first perform a cheap test:

```
b.size < a.size
```

If that is true there certainly will be at least one element of `a` that is not in `b` (assuming that `a` contains no duplicates).

Comment: Just knowing that somethings is missing is ok to finish the process. I also have means to find out if (3..9) is `b` range or is even bigger and that is a way to finish early too.

Comment: By the way `b` size is unknown, It could contain 5 numbers or millions.

Comment: @Elo That's one way of saying "this might be quick, or it might be slow". There's no algorithmic magic bullet here. You're looking at *O(n log(n))* at best here most probably unless you can be more specific. If you're dealing with a large number of range limited values, a bitmask could crush this problem in an instant.